# ErrorException Trying to get property 'kode_buyer' of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Im trying to populate my dropdown with data from my database

Heres my Model :

```
public function getBuyer($slug = false)
{
    if ($slug == false) {
        return $this->findAll();
    }

    return $this->where(['kode_divisi' => $slug])->first();
}
```

Controllers :

```
public function produksi()
{
    $data = [
        'main' => 'buyer/produksi',
        'title' => 'List Produksi',
        'hasil' => $this->buyerModel->getbuyer()
    ];
    return view('template/template', $data);
}
```

And View :

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<div class="content-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header bg-info" style="text-align: center;">
                        <h2>Form Tambah Data Pegawai</h2>
                    </div>
                    <form action="/pegawai/save" method="post">
                        <?= csrf_field(); ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="kode_divisi" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Kode Divisi</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="date" name="bday" max="3000-12-31" 
                                min="1000-01-01" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Buyer</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select required name="kode_gejala">
                                    <option value="" disabled diselected>-- Pilih Buyer --</option>
                                    <?php                                
                                    foreach ($hasil as $row) {  
                                        echo "<option value='".$row->kode_buyer."'>".$row->nama_buyer."</option>";
                                    }
                                    echo"
                                    </select>"
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nama_pegawai" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nama Pegawai</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama_pegawai" name="nama_pegawai" value="<?= old('nama_pegawai'); ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="job_desc" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Job Desc</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="job_desc" name="job_desc" value="<?= old('job_desc'); ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Tambah Data</button>
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" href="/pegawai" role="button"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Batal</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it gave my this error:

> ErrorException Trying to get property 'kode_buyer' of non-object

it says that this line is the cause of the error:

```
echo "<option value='".$row->kode_buyer."'>".$row->nama_buyer."</option>";
```

Is there a way to fix this? i already try some alternate way, but it lead to the same error

Im using Codeigniter 4 BTW.

Comment: how about $data['hasil'] as $row in foreach?

Comment: can you dump and show us the contents of `$data['hasil']`

Comment: change this  `'hasil' => $this->buyerModel->getbuyer()` to `getBuyer()`

Comment: check what `echo'<pre>';print_r($hasil);die; spits out. `Put this line before your foreach loop. You'll see the array/object structure or if there is no value at all. Take it from there.

Comment: @Vickel It show the dropdown, but it doesnt show data from my database

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir it showing no data, why is that?

Comment: @ArashShiri already do that, it gave the same error

Comment: @KUMAR Still show the same error

Comment: also do `dd($data)` in your controller before the return statement

Comment: it show :

array(3) { ["main"]=> string(14) "buyer/produksi" ["title"]=> string(13) "List Produksi" ["dataku"]=> object(stdClass)#87 (5) { ["kode_buyer"]=> string(5) "IK001" ["nama_buyer"]=> string(13) "Ik Collection" ["pic"]=> string(13) "Wanda Purnomo" ["no_tlp"]=> string(1) "0" ["alamat"]=> string(6) "Cimahi" } }

and yeah that was my data from table that im using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as by your comment, your data looks like this:

```
array(3) { ["main"]=> string(14) "buyer/produksi" 
           ["title"]=> string(13) "List Produksi" 
           ["dataku"]=> object(stdClass)#87 (5) { 
                ["kode_buyer"]=> string(5) "IK001" 
                ["nama_buyer"]=> string(13) "Ik Collection" ["pic"]=> string(13) "Wanda Purnomo" 
                ["no_tlp"]=> string(1) "0" 
                ["alamat"]=> string(6) "Cimahi" 
           } 
         }
```

This means `kode_buyer` is not at array's top level, but a nested object of `dataku`, therefore `$row->kode_buyer` gives you an error, as it doesn't exist there. You need to access kode_buyer that way:

```
$row["dataku"]->kode_buyer
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly.
Also i wanna ask, where can i ask something directly about how to code something. Like lets say i wanna ask "How to make dynamic dropdown but without primary key id" cause i know you cant ask something like that here, the reason why i wanna ask this is cause i already try several way to make it but just dint work,  even google doesn't have an answer for that.
so yeah it would be helpful if you know where i could ask something like that.

Comment: In answer to your comment: You can ask that kind of question, show and describe the problem you are running in, what you have tried, why it doesn't work and just show the **essential** code to reproduce your problem and read
[**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
as well as [**How to Ask a Good Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok, gonna follow your instruction and try to make a question out of it. Thanks again btw